# Mapping callsite to thread stack in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, bytecode, instrumentation

I'm using bytecode instrumentation to gather call graph at runtime. One thing I can't get the call relationship between threads because each thread has its own stack.

```
foo() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            bar();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

How do I trace which method starts the thread? My aim is to find:

foo() [context main thread] can reach bar() [context another thread]

More context: My instrumentation pushes the method onto the stack when entering it, pop it from the stack after exiting. To deal with multithreading environment, each thread will use a new stack.

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll be able to reconstruct `foo() -> bar()` as there's going to be `foo() -> Thread.start() [-> possiblyMoreCalls()] -> Runnable.run() -> bar()` in there too

Comment: I rephrased my question, is bar() reachable from foo()?

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to do a static or dynamic analysis? With a static analysis, some forms of this will always be impossible (imagine `void foo(Runnable r) { new Thread(r).start(); }`, what can that "reach"?). With a dynamic analysis (with runtime instrumentation) then you just need to intercept every call to `Thread::start` and store information about the caller's call stack at that point. For example, you could have a global `WeakHashMap<Thread, StackTraceElement[]>` or something which you could fill in at the point where the thread is started.

Comment: It is a dynamic analysis. Thread.start() does not provide any information about which thread is invoked.

Comment: How does `Thread.start()` “not provide any information about which thread is invoked”? It’s the object on which `start()` is invoked.

Comment: @Saddy: Worth noting that most well-factored code won't call `Thread::start` directly, at least not very often. For example, if you're using an `Executor`, the thread that backs the executor may have been started from code that is completely unrelated to the code that submits a `Runnable` or `Callable` into the `Executor`. So you need similar interception tooling at those points, which might actually be easier to implement. For example, you could write a `StackCapturingExecutor` implementation that stores caller information -- you don't need any bytecode instrumentation to do that.

Comment: @DanielPryden I think I got it. Thanks